# Find count of a key based on certain conditions javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I suppose the answer [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) is different from what I want to achieve. The above link questions about accessing object in from a nested array set.

I have an array of objects like below

```
[
 {
   "type": "type 1",
   "status": "success"
 },
 {
   "type": "type 2",
   "status": "success"
 },
 {
   "type": "type 1",
   "status": "error"
 },
 {
   "type": "type 1",
   "status": "success"
 }
]
```

What I intend to get is something like this

```
 2 type 1 has an event success
 1 type 1 has an event error
 1 type 2 has an event success
```

Basically, I want the count of type whose status is success and error.

underscore.js might be useful here, but I could not make that happen.
Help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked dup candidate can very well be applied to your task. If you need a copy-pasta answer, then it's not suitable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following, you can use `_.countBy`

```
var arr = [
 {
   "type": "type 1",
   "status": "success"
 },
 {
   "type": "type 2",
   "status": "success"
 },
 {
   "type": "type 1",
   "status": "error"
 },
 {
   "type": "type 1",
   "status": "success"
 }
];

var res = _.countBy(arr,function(obj){
return obj.type + " has an event " + obj.status
});

for(var item in res)
{
   console.log(res[item] + " " + item);
}
```